# Libpng error at :app:mergeDebugResources - Gradle Error 42

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, libpng

When compiling my app for debug in Android Studio, I get the following error(s):

```
Failed to run command:
C:\Users\Farbod\Android-SDK\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe s -i C:\Users\Farbod\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\img_myImage.png -o C:\Users\Me\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\img_myImage.png
Error Code:
42
Output:
C:\Users\Me\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\img_myImage.png: libpng warning: IDAT: Too many IDATs found
libpng error: Read Error
:app:mergeDebugResrouces FAILED
```

I've checked that all my files are in a `.png` format, and I'm not sure what could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **SOLUTION**

I tried opening my file (`img_myImage.png`) in Adobe Fireworks, which wouldn't open the file, so I opened it in Photoshop which *did* work, and then I re-saved it as a `.png` file, which seemed to solve the issue.

Comment: the solution is good, but how to get which image is exactly that caused the issue ?